# How to import and run a django function at the command line

Tags: python, django

I have a Django function "get_data_from_text_file()" that I want to test run from the command line. I tried:

```
>>> import v1.views
>>> get_data_from_text_file("kk")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'get_data_from_text_file' is not defined
```

Why is it not defined if its imported sucessfully?

Comment: Because that's not how Python modules work.

Comment: I'm kinda new to python, can you explain further, so I can test this function at the command line?

Comment: You'd probably want to run `v1.views.get_data_from_text_file` is my guess . . .

Comment: Keep in mind it won't work if it uses anything django related unless you run `python manage.py shell` and use that instead of your normal python shell.

Comment: thanks, it turned out to work when I used >>> v1.views.get_data_from_text_file("kk")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all make sure you're using `manage.py shell` and not plain `python` in the command line to make this test.

You're not importing the get_data_from_text_file function, but all the view. You could either use:

> v1.views.get_data_from_text_file("kk")

or try to do the import like this:

> from v1.views import get_data_from_text_file